# Bootstrap Fluid Container with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use boostrap 3 along with AngularJS in the following way :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col col-md-2 sidebar" ng-controller="NavBarCtrl">
</div>
<div class="col col-md-10">
        <div ng-view class="fadeZoom"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
Inside the 10 columns layout i'm loading a view with Angular. My question is; is it possible to make the content that i'm loading into this div (the 10 columns wide one) to only contain 10 columns and not 12 ? Since my design is based on a 12 columns grid system, i have to refine the positioning in the 10 columns div since the content in this one will be 12 columns wide.

In bootstrap 2.3 there was this thing called Scaffolding which is different in Boostrap 3. 
E.G: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html - Scroll down to Fluid layout .
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest nesting a row within the col-md-10 so that you can use a 12 col grid for your ng-view div. If you choose not to nest a row that's okay too. In that case you will have 10 columns to work with. The controllers have no affect on the end result. The columns function just as they would if those views were not there.

Comment: If you run into issues with your ng-view container overlapping with your navbarctrl, you can consider offsetting your columns by 2. Offset columns is a feature of Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Patrick Motard by offsetting my columns i would end up with a 12 columns grid inside a 10 columns grid . I want to use something like : this 10 columns grid inside 10 columns grid ... all the same width

Comment: My ideal flow will be <div class = col-md-12> <div class= col-md-2></div> <div class = col-md-10> 10 columns not 12 </div></div>

Comment: if i'll not use rows inside the div i'm telling you about i'll end up in Bootstrap's hell :)

Comment: Please look at the section of the bootstrap documentation found [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) called "Offsetting Columns" and let me know if we're on the same page. There are two possible outcomes that come to mind: 1) your ng-view does not overlap (i don't think it will) in which case you can give your ng-view a simple col-10 while it's in the same row as the col-2 and it will work as expected. 2) use offset like .col-md-10 .col-md-offset-2.

Comment: well, i've tried this, but my problem is that when i'm creating the col-md-10 and i create a row inside it i end up with 12 columns not 10 ... it will be a solution to inject angulars ng-view in a 12 column & offset everything by 2 columns ?

Comment: It sounds like you understand what i'm suggesting but are hesitant about dealing with 12 columns inside of a 10 col width row. When you're nesting this is unavoidable and as scary as you think. Keep your nested rows at a width of 12 for your own sanity. It gets very messy otherwise. I find it helpful to think of col in terms of percentages instead of chunks. Thats how you handle making responsive design by hand. The nice thing about 12 col in every nest is that it's easily divisible into nice round percentages, 10th's are not.

Comment: Offsetting will only be a viable option if there is overlap between the two divs and i don't think there will be. If there is no overlap you will run into there being a 2 col wide gap between the col-2 and the nested col-10 that is offset by 2.

Comment: What concerns me is that i have a design with 12 columns straight & i want to respect it as much as possible. In this design layout i have 2 columns with the sidebar and 10 columns of content structured as following : several 2 column elements. In my code, when i'm getting into this part, inside the 10 columns div i have 12 columns & it isn't respecting the design

Comment: I will attach a screenshot now so you can better understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68751/discussion-between-patrick-motard-and-alexandru-serban).